# not showing table rows

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

Hi am trying to execute this search code but its showing only column names not the rows.

```
@WebServlet("/SearchEmployee")
public class SearchEmployee extends HttpServlet {
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   String fname = request.getParameter("fullname");
   String desg = request.getParameter("designation");
   String email = request.getParameter("email");
   String uname = request.getParameter("username");
   String password = request.getParameter("password");

   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", "root", "root");

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from reg where  fname=? or desg=? or email=? or uname=? or pass=?");

    ps.setString(1, fname);
    ps.setString(2, desg);
    ps.setString(3, email);
    ps.setString(4, uname);
    ps.setString(5, password);


    request.getRequestDispatcher("./Home.jsp").include(request, response);
    out.println("<table id=\"mytable\">");

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int total = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    out.print("<tr>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
     out.print("<th>" + rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "</th>");
    }

    out.print("</tr>");

    while (rs.next()) {


     out.print("<tr><td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(5) + "</td></tr>");


    }

    out.print("</table>");

   } catch (Exception e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: does it give you any error ,post it

Comment: Missing doGet method

Comment: when i add doGet instead of service method it showing error like this .. HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: no errors for this code.